# Begin:comparison Statement in procedural block

Tags: verilog, fpga, hdl

As part of a lecture series on verilog HDL for FPGA programming I have been given this piece of code to create a signed 8-bit greater-than comparator. I have simulated this in xillinx ISE and it shows that the syntax is correct. However I do not understand the `begin:comparison` line. I understand that in the procedural `@always(*)` block a begin and end statement is needed, however, in this case when the `:comparison` is removed the module no longer compiles.

My best guess would be that the `:comparison` is referring to the `sgt = intA > int B;` line however I cant understand why or find much information about begin and end statements in that form.

```
module sgtc(input [7:0] a,b, output reg sgt);
always@(*) begin:comparison

   integer intA, intB;
   intA = a;
   intB = b;
   sgt = intA > intB;

end

endmodule
```

Comment: It always help to show the compiler error when you need help with understanding a construct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`comparison` is just the name of the block. The author of the code could have called it anything legal. However, in Verilog, you had to name a block if you wanted to declare a variable inside it, which is exactly what you are doing:

```
integer intA, intB;
```

So, when you removed the name, this becomes illegal Verilog, which is why it won't compile (in a Verilog-only compiler).

The restriction of having to name a block if you declare a variable inside it is lifted in System-Verilog. So, if you use a compiler that understands this aspect of System-Verilog, then it will compile.

Comment: I wanted to add that if you remove the block name in SystemVerilog, you won't be able to access the variables declared inside the block from outside the named block  - they become local to the block.